# Cannot intercept 401 Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-http-interceptors

I have been trying to intercept 401 responses when I hit an API but it has been frustratingly not working at all.

When I visit a particular link, on the browser console, I can see that it is responding with 401. Basically I want to redirect it to my login page whenever it encounters such responses. I have seen a lot of the questions here and tried to do something similar but it is not working.

Here is the contents of my main.js file.

```
var app = angular.module('strelsau_client', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'angularCSS']).config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {

// Intercept http calls.
$provide.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
return {
  // On request success
  request: function (config) {
     console.log(config); // Contains the data about the request before it is sent.

    // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
    return config || $q.when(config);
  },

  // On request failure
  requestError: function (rejection) {
     console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.

    // Return the promise rejection.
    return $q.reject(rejection);
  },

  // On response success
  response: function (response) {
     console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.

    // Return the response or promise.
    return response || $q.when(response);
  },

  // On response failture
  responseError: function (rejection) {
    console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error.

    // Return the promise rejection.
    return $q.reject(rejection);
  }
};
});

// Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider.
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');

});


app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/bookings/fare.html',
        controller: 'BookingsCtrl',
        css: ['../assets/css/stylesheet.css']
    })
    .when('/admin',{
        templateUrl:'views/admin/index.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        css: ['../assets/css/vendor.css','../assets/css/flat-admin.css']

    })
            .when('/admin/taxis',{
        templateUrl:'views/admin/taxis.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        css: ['../assets/css/vendor.css','../assets/css/flat-admin.css']

    })

            .when('/admin/customers',{
        templateUrl:'views/admin/customers.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        css: ['../assets/css/vendor.css','../assets/css/flat-admin.css']

    })

    .when('/admin/set_price', {
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/set_price.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl'
    })

    .when('/admin/adddriver', {
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/add_taxi_driver.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl'
    })
            .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

Comment: didn't you forgot to test the 401 error in *responseError* in order to redirect ? Note : you can use $httpProvider.interceptors.push({[object]]) instead of creating a factory inside angular that don't have other purpose.

Comment: @Walfrat I'm sorry  but I really don't get what you are saying. None of the console.log is showing anything.

Comment: try `$httpProvider.interceptors.push({responseError: function (rejection){console.log(rejection); return $q.reject(rejection);}});`

Comment: Should I remove the factory and just insert your snippet?

Comment: I tried it. But nothing is showing on my console.

Comment: You code works, just fine. Are you sure your api is returning a 401, check using chrome debugging tool

Comment: just in case : are you sure the module `strelsau_client` is present in a `ng-app` of referenced by the module called in `ng-app` tag ?

Comment: yes it is present. I have a service which gets me some data from the api. If i remove the required authentication in the API, it works correctly ( I get the data). Now , it seems to work since  I can get this message in the browser  GET http://localhost:3000/admin/customers 401 (Unauthorized) ) But I can't figure out how to redirect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did the interception at the service level. Here is how I did it :

```
app.service('AdminService', function($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:3000/admin/customers',{},{
query:{
    method: 'GET',
        interceptor: {
    response:function(data){
        console.log("success");
    },
    responseError: function(data){
        window.location="/#/admin/login";
    }
}
},

});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna post my working code below so you can compare and adjust yours:

```
angular.module("application").config(['$httpProvider' ,function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope','$q','$location','$injector', function($rootScope, $q, $location, $injector) {
      return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
              var $state = $injector.get('$state');

              if(rejection.status <= 0) {

              }else if (rejection.status == 401) {
                  // Here I pick my 401
              }else if (rejection.status == 404) {
                  //$state.go('404');
              }else if (rejection.status == 500) {
                  $state.go('500');
              }
              return $q.reject(rejection);
          }
      };
    }
  ]);
 }
]);
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: for the record : the *$state* is reitrieved using $injector otherwise you will have a circular reference error if you try to inject it as usual.